# send parameters of form via URL

Tags: forms, parameters, get

I have a form like this:

```
<form rel="search" action="/archives">

 <input name="keyword" type="text" value="search..." />

 <input type="submit" value=submit" name="submit" />

</form>
```

When a User click on submit...I want sent parameters by URL...

exact this URL:  http://examole.com/archives/keyword

Or any alternative way...

.

Is it possible?

---

Edit

I try change above code to this:

```
<form rel="search" action="/archives" method="get">

 <input name="keyword" type="text" value="search..." />

 <input type="submit" value="submit"  />

</form>
```

The result:

```
http://127.0.0.1/archives?keyword=search...
```

How can I change The URL to this:

```
   http://127.0.0.1/archives/search...
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Just use `method="get"`

```
<form method="get" rel="search" action="/archives">
   <input name="keyword" type="text" value="search..." />
   <input type="submit" value=submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for the asnwer...But how can I get a clean URL..please note my last edit :)